# Replace commas in a input field if only number is entered but not text : in the text field

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a running code for removing comma in the text field,
but i need to remove comma only when the entered value is **number** then comma should be removed, but not for text

Code :

```
JS :
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#textField").on('keyup', function(){
            this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, "");
        });
    });
</script>      

HTML : 
<input type="text" id="textField" placeholder="" value="" />
```

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/66kTS/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`isNaN()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) method for checking it is a number or not

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#textField").on('keyup', function(){
            if(!isNaN(this.value.replace(/,/g, "")))
                 this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, "");
        });
    });
</script>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/66kTS/3/)

or you can use regular expression using [**`match()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#textField").on('keyup', function(){
            if(this.value.match(/^\d*,\d*$/))
                 this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, "");
        });
    });
</script>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/66kTS/6/)

Comment: this code is not working.
Showing Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this

Comment: why 2 time : "this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, "");" can u plz tell me.

Comment: One is for checking that is a number or not, second one is for replacing the `,`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, no need to import jQuery also, working fine in all the browsers.

```
<input type="text" id="textField" placeholder="" value="" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/,/g, '')"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.value != null && this.value.match(/^\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})*?(.\d*)?$/)){
    this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, "");
}
```

Comment: That won't identify any values with either a `.` or a `,` in it, numeric or otherwise.

Comment: Good point, and obviously silly if it doesn't even see the comma!  I think @Pranav's answer is more reliable in that sense, but let's see if we can at least improve this Regex.   Updated to include commas and periods.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$("#textField").on('keyup', function(){
    if(this.value.match(/[0-9]/g) != null) {
        this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, "");
    }
});
```